# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra 'ululofilia'?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, neologismos

La [*ululofilia*](http://supermileto.blogspot.com.es/2016/07/la-ululofilia.html) hace referencia a la colección de figuras de aves rapaces nocturnas (búhos o lechuzas artesanales).
Si bien es un término muy poco usado (no lo vi registrado en el DLE y la búsqueda rápida de internet remite a algunos blogs), no me queda claro cuál es el origen de la palabra. No sé cuál es su traducción (que sería la forma más fácil de hallarle origen) aunque la etimología a grandes rasgos mostraría al sufijo '-filia' que supone "afición", y lo de *ululo*, quizá de alguna lengua germánica.

¿Conocen desde hace cuánto el término se usa en español y de dónde proviene?

Comment: lechuza en latín es *ulula*, lo que no se si primero es el animal o se llama así por el sonido que hace, yo apostaría por lo segundo.

Comment: también en español hay un animal llamado [úlula](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/frames.aspx?es=%C3%BAlula) parecido a una lechuza

Comment: El verbo _ulular_ es un cultismo, o sea, una palabra española que se mantuvo casi invariable desde el latín, y actualmente casi no se usa. Pero evolucionó hacia otra palabra que sí es mucho más usada, aunque su significado cambió ligeramente: _aullar_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como bien apuntan en los comentarios, es una palabra compuesta de [***ulula***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulula#Latin), latín para 'lechuza', y el sufijo [***-filia***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HuXOblN) que significa 'afición'.

El motivo de cambiar la última 'a' por una 'o' puede ser para facilitar la pronunciación, o por analogía con [colombofilia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9plBiws) que viene de *columba* (paloma).

En español tenemos el verbo *ulular* para indicar el sonido que hacen las lechuzas y búhos pero, sorprendentemente, [el DLE no recoge esa acepción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b3VReXo). Choca más todavía que sí recoja la de "hacer ruido el viento" cuando seguramente ese uso venga de la similaridad con el canto de los búhos, pero en fin, esto ya es divagar :D

Comment: [Alguien](http://etimologias.dechile.net/PIE/?ul) dice que la palabra latina a su vez proviene de una hipotética raíz protoindoeuropea *ul- (aullar, gritos de dolor y lamentos fúnebres).

Comment: That's interesting. So what do you call the sound made in a style of singing and elsewhere which in English we call ululation?

Answer (score 0):

ulular es cuando el búho emite sonido e incluso se le llama al sonido de los lobos. Por si sirve de algo la relación ;)